# How can I ensure all output from Ant's exec task goes to stdout?

Tags: ant, exec

The Ant `exec` task has an output property which can be used to tell Ant where the output goes. I've used it to redirect the output to a file. The thing is, if I don't do something with the output, the stuff that Ant prints isn't that much of a help - it's not complete.

Is there someway of setting the output property to `System.out`?

Answer (score 16):

When executing a batch file with ant's `apply` or `exec` tasks on Windows, I found there are special cases where some of the stdout and stderr is not captured by ant. (For example: if you call a batch file that in turn calls other commands (like `node.exe`), then the stdout and stderror from the child `node.exe` process is lost.)

I spent a long time trying to debug this! It seems that the batch file's stdout and stderr is captured, however commands called by the batch file are somehow not seen by ant. (perhaps because they are separate child processes).  Using the `output` and `error` attributes as suggested above doesn't help because only *some* of the stdout and/or stderr is captured.

The solution I came up with (a *hack*) is to add these arguments at the end of the command:

```
<!--Next arg: forces node's stderror and stdout to a temporary file-->
<arg line=" &gt; _tempfile.out 2&lt;&amp;1"/>

<!--Next arg: If command exits with an error, then output the temporary file to stdout, -->
<!--delete the temporary file and finally exit with error level 1 so that    -->
<!--the apply task can catch the error if @failonerror="true"                -->
<arg line=" || (type _tempfile.out &amp; del _tempfile.out &amp; exit /b 1)"/>

<!--Next arg: Otherwise, just type the temporary file and delete it-->
<arg line=" &amp; type _tempfile.out &amp; del _tempfile.out &amp;"/>
```

Because this *hack* only applies to windows, remember to add `@osfamily="windows"` to the `apply` or `exec` task.  And create similar task(s) for `@osfamily="unix", etc but without these extra arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The output of `exec` **does** go to standard out **unless** you specify the `output` attribute.

Comment: The output ant's giving is not the full output. If I redirect it to a file, I get a totally different thing.

Comment: This is true for unix systems. But on windows systems, if you call a batch file that in turn calls other commands (like `node.exe`), then the stdout and stderror from the child node.exe process is lost.  See the _hack_ I describe as an answer if you're on windows and having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output to System.out, then simply do not specify the "output" attribute. If you would like to redirect to a file AND print it to System.out, you can use the [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) command, which will redirect output to a given file and also echo it to standard out... I do not know if Windows supports "tee" or an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look at the `error`, `logError`, and `errorproperty` attributes of the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task too.  These deal with the handling of the standard error stream from the exec'd process.  There may be useful information there that is going awol for some reason - which might account for the incompleteness you see.

But, if the exec'd process decides to close stdout or stderr and send them elsewhere - there's little you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem: the output of command execution was suppressed. Perhaps that is the side effect when running `cmd` under WinXP (I an using `maven-antrun-plugin`). Anyway setting `output="con"` worked out perfectly:

```
<configuration>
    <target>
        <exec executable="cmd" output="con">
            <arg value="/c" />
            <arg value="..." />
        </exec>
    </target>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working with Ant and Gruntjs:**

For anyone trying to get this to work using Gruntjs. I was able to get it working by doing the following (*in combination with darcyparker's answer*).

**In my Ant Build File:**

```
<target description="run grunt js tasks" name="grunt">  
    <exec  dir="/path/to/grunt" executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="jshint.bat"/> // I broke each task into it's own exec
        <arg line=" &gt; jshint.log 2&lt;&amp;1"/>
        <arg line=" || (type jshint.log &amp; del jshint.log &amp; exit /b 1)"/>
        <arg line=" &amp; type jshint.log &amp; del jshint.log &amp;"/>
    </exec>
    <exec  dir="/path/to/grunt" executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
        // another grunt task (IE: uglify, cssmin, ect..)
    </exec>
</target>
```

**jshint.bat**

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\path\to\grunt\" 
@ECHO _____________________________________________
@ECHO GRUNT JSHINT
@ECHO _____________________________________________
grunt jshint --stack >>jshint.log
```

**NOTE:** Path to grunt would be where your ***Gruntfile.js*** is located. Also note, I had to initially create the log file (*to get it to work with darcyparker's answer*)  which would output the stack trace from that particular task. This would then give me the grunt task stack output from wherever I call my ant target.

Finally note that `pushd "C:\path\to\grunt\"` won't be necissary if your bat files are in the same directory as your `Gruntfile.js`.

Answer (score -1):

I was experiencing this same kind of issue trying to get the build process to fail in Ant after Karma tests intentionally failed, and executing them with "grunt test".

Just added /c before "grunt test", and it worked like a charm

```
<target name="unittest">
    <echo>*** KARMA UNIT TESTING ***</echo>
    <exec dir="api_ui" executable="cmd" osfamily="windows" logError="yes" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="/c grunt test"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```