# How do I redirect maven's antrun exec command's output to stdout?

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I have this antrun task, which uses the "exec" command ...

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-xvfb</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="Starting xvfb ..." />
                            <exec executable="Xvfb" spawn="true" failonerror="true">
                                <arg value=":0.0" />
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Although I can see the echo statement in my output, I can't see any of the executables output in standard out.  What can I do to redirect it to the same place that the echo message goes to?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: For anyone reaching to this question, in `maven-antrun-plugin`:`3.x` the `task` is replaced with `execution`.

Answer (score 7):

The **spawn** option is the problem. See the [ant exec task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

> If you spawn a command, its output will not be logged by ant.

Furthermore, make sure there is no `output` or `output property` present, as they will redirect the output to a property or file (see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602616/how-can-i-ensure-all-output-from-ants-exec-task-goes-to-stdout)).