# How do I display ANT exec task output in the same CMD window?

Tags: java, ant, cmd, oracle-adf, build.xml

I am trying to build an ADF application using ANT from the command line, by making use of OJDeploy.

In the build.xml OJDeploy is executed on the CMD line using an exec task, I need to display the output from this task on the same command line.

I have tried running ANT with the -v option, and writing the output to a file but it does not give any of the output from OJDeploy executing.

Comment: You're going to be way better off using the ojdeploy ant task.

Comment: Please can you explain why.

Comment: For starters, all of it's output would show up in the right place.  It's just genearlly cleaner to keep it all in ant, rather than exec out.  You'll have nice named parameters to the task rather than many arg values to exec.

Answer (score 4):

See [How can I ensure all output from Ant's exec task goes to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602616/how-can-i-ensure-all-output-from-ants-exec-task-goes-to-stdout/1602976#1602976)

Or perhaps.

> ```
> <exec outputproperty="output" ... />
> <echo message="${output}" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply calling "ojdeploy64" instead of "ojdeploy". After I did that the output was shown in the command line as I expected.